# java script doesn't work in my django project

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

recently I add a new template to my my django project and the html and css load properly but my java script and jquery doesn't executed at all.
this are my codes :

```js
//jQuery time
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

$(".next").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 next_fs = $(this).parent().next();
 
 //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
 
 //show the next fieldset
 next_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
   scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
   left = (now * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({
        'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
        'position': 'absolute'
      });
   next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".previous").click(function(){
 if(animating) return false;
 animating = true;
 
 current_fs = $(this).parent();
 previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();
 
 //de-activate current step on progressbar
 $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");
 
 //show the previous fieldset
 previous_fs.show(); 
 //hide the current fieldset with style
 current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
  step: function(now, mx) {
   //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
   //1. scale previous_fs from 80% to 100%
   scale = 0.8 + (1 - now) * 0.2;
   //2. take current_fs to the right(50%) - from 0%
   left = ((1-now) * 50)+"%";
   //3. increase opacity of previous_fs to 1 as it moves in
   opacity = 1 - now;
   current_fs.css({'left': left});
   previous_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')', 'opacity': opacity});
  }, 
  duration: 800, 
  complete: function(){
   current_fs.hide();
   animating = false;
  }, 
  //this comes from the custom easing plugin
  easing: 'easeInOutBack'
 });
});

$(".submit").click(function(){
 return false;
})
```

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.6), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.6));
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 400px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: relative;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 width: 33.33%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- multistep form -->
<form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">Account Setup</li>
    <li>Social Profiles</li>
    <li>Personal Details</li>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

in this code when I click to 'next' button, java script should take me to next fieldset tag in my html, but even this isn't work.
is this about my java script code or this problem is because of Django?
**In Addision, I'm sorry for writing mistakes in my question.**

Comment: Did your include your javascript file in your template using a `<script>` tag? I can only see you included `jQuery`. Also see [Managing Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css).

Comment: yes, and I put script tag in end of body tag, after my html codes.

Comment: @trixn now I put all of this code in a .html file , but it doesn't work too,
the problem is because of java script code, but I can't find out the problem.

Comment: Open the inspector/debugger of your browser and look for errors.

Comment: @Selcuk its write `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
What is this mean?

Comment: your jquery is not loading

Comment: show the footer where you add the jquery and your js file

Comment: @BernardParah I Reference jQuery first then put my java script code, and why jquery code doesn't load?

Comment: open your devtools> network>js . confirm if the jquery is actually loaded

Comment: this is my all code :
[link](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IJQWW)

Comment: What are those files you have attached? Which one loads first? You are obviously trying to use jQuery before it loads.

Comment: @BernardParah  devtools> network>js is empty.
you mean this page? : [link](https://ibb.co/ef69ZT)

Comment: @Selcuk I didn't attached any file , I put my jQuery and my java script code in script tag as you can see in my snippet code .

Comment: your jquery is obviously not loading. load the jquery from the base template. should be in your base.html and inherited by other templates

Comment: @BernardParah I copy and use this code from this link and there isn't any thing else :
[link](https://codepen.io/atakan/pen/gqbIz)

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
this line, add it to the base.html of your project. Remove it from where it currently is

Comment: @BernardParah you mean "src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"
or this "src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1"?

Comment: the whole script that loads your jquery, move that tag to the base.html

Comment: @BernardParah I put this to my project and its load but when I press "Next" button page load like this : [link](https://ibb.co/kRO3To) and its not load properly.

Comment: use your console to debug this one, your jquery is loading now, so you need to find what the next error is

Comment: @BernardParah I use console and it I face this error :
`Uncaught TypeError:
w.easing[this.easing] is not a function
    at init.run (jquery.min.js:2)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.w.fx.tick (jquery.min.js:2)
    at at (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.w.fx.start (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.w.fx.timer (jquery.min.js:2)
    at pt (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFieldSetElement.a (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.dequeue (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFieldSetElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)`

Comment: try loading jquery at the top.

Comment: @doubleo46 I already do it, but it doesn’t affect.

Comment: where exactly is the javascript snippet at the top or bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap it's also possible that Bootstrap's jQuery, if included below your jQuery script tag, is overwriting your jQuery script tag with another version. Including jQuery's own CDN and deleting the jQuery script tag that Bootstrap provides was the only thing that worked for me.
so the only thing that you have to do is put this Script tag to your html tag:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

now the script will be load as you expect.